# Summation using binomial coefficient

Tags: summation

I am trying to calculate the following using binomial coefficients and summation, but my memory is standing in the way:

$$
   \sum_{k=1}^n {k} * 2 ^ {k - 1}
$$

Thanks!

With great help I got to:

$$ (n - 1)* 2 ^{n} - 1 $$

Can you please confirm this?

Comment: Have you checked your formula, for say $n=1$?

Comment: @robjohn I found the mistake a while ago, I will update. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: switch to polynomial functions.
$$
 P(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}
$$

Comment: Integrate $P$, get a closed-form "nice" expression of its antiderivative, differentiate this expression to get a "nice" expression of $P$; use this to evaluate $P(2)$.

Comment: I find something different (namely, $(n-1)2^n+1$). To test whether your answer is right, do a sanity check by computing it for small values of $n$ (0, 1, 2 or even 3.)

Answer (score 3):

Clement C's solution is the best approach. There is another approach, however.

Notice that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k 2^{k-1}
$$
because $k=\sum_{i=1}^k 1$. By reversing the order of summation, you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^{k-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=i}^n 2^{k-1}
$$
A closed form solution can now be found easily for the inner sum, which will produce a form that can be used to find a closed form solution for the outer sum.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n+1}{j+1}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nk\,2^{k-1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\,\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n(j+1)\binom{k}{j+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)\binom{n+1}{j+2}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^nj\binom{n+1}{j+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(j+1)\binom{n+1}{j+1}-\binom{n+1}{j+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(n+1)\binom{n}{j}-\binom{n+1}{j+1}\\
&=(n+1)(2^n-1)-(2^{n+1}-n-2)\\[12pt]
&=(n-1)2^n+1
\end{align}
$$

---

**Verification**

Of course, to verify, we can try induction.

The formula works for $n=1$: $1=1$.

Assume the formula works for $n-1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nk\,2^{k-1}
&=n\,2^{n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\,2^{k-1}\\
&=n\,2^{n-1}+(n-2)2^{n-1}+1\\[9pt]
&=(n-1)2^n+1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, it is true for all $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approch

∑k.2^(k-1)

Let f(x)=∑k.x^(k-1)

∫f(x) dx=∑∫k.x^(k-1)dx

∫f(x) dx=∑x^k

∫f(x)dx= x +x^2 + x^3 + …………………. X^n

∫f(x) dx= x(x^n-1)/(x-1)

Differentiating both sides

f(x)= ( nx^(n+1) –(n+1)x^n + 1)/(x-1)^2

put x=2  f(2)=(n-1)2^n +1

Comment: please consider writing this in latex...